# Linux fs.writeFileSync() doesnt write to files until app is closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Using windows my code I currently use:

```
var file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath), 'utf8');
file[id] = JSON.parse(`{"name":name}`);
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(file,null,2);
```

This works just fine on windows. However, when I transfer this code onto my linux machine for cross-platform testing. The file doesn't get updated until I stop running the application.

What i've tried:

> running 'chmod -r 0777 path/to/dir/'

and

> checked if it was due to max file open limit (not the case as my limit is extremely large)

Linux: Mint-Linux 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu (from uname -a)

Node: 8.10.0

Editor: intelliJ idea

Im also running the code directly from the run button in intelliJ, im not sure if this may be the cause, if it is the cause why would this be the case.

Comment: You may want to include in the question ... which version of node, which distro and release of linux - because, that simply does not happen - also, try to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example that demonstrates the issue

Comment: Do you really use that code? `var json[id] = JSON.parse('{"name":name}');` doesn't look valid to me.

Comment: The code provided in the text was actually wrong... I have fixed it and as for my actual code I do use pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the option {mode: 0o777} as the last arg in the write fixed the files not updating.